# How to use Jquery Objects to insert in cells in the midde of a dynamical created Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The company I work for has a html table that can be designed by the user.
The table is put into JQuery objects by using `closest('table')`
We allow columns to be added but the one problem we have is the following.
When we try and insert a cell into column into the middle of the table `insertbefore` or `insertafter` does not work. 
it does not create a `td` into the middle of the row, therefore as anyone got any idea we can shift the cells to the left by one cell.
The structure of the table is in collection of row objects that has cells array by using the `cellIndex`.
The table structure is not updated till all cells are added for the column and have been added and adjusted for `rowSpan` or `colSpan`.
 the code below is how we try and insert at present.

```
     self.newCell '<td data-cmstype="container"><p class="editor-temp">New Cell</p></td>'
     var leftSpanedCell = row[cellindex];
     var newCell = $(self.newCellHtml);
     newCell.insertBefore(leftSpanedCell.td);
```

Comment: `<p>` elements do not belong inside a `<td>`

Comment: How about an example link or a JSFiddle?

Comment: Cannot put to much code here but thansk for your reply as for you cannot put paragraphs of course you can, it does not break nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to decrease any span or rowspans and redraw the row table with the objects 
I also needed to create my cells properly by creating an object as cell I needed to create an object and then set it to the row array.

```
     var obj = {};
     obj.td = $(self.newCellHtml).insertAfter(td);
     obj.col = newTD;
     obj.length = colSpan
     obj.row = cell.row;
     thisrow[newTD] = obj
```